# How do I fix this random.choice issue in python?

Tags: python, macos, bots

I am working on a little NON-AI (till now) Chatbot with Python 3.7. and now I wanted random to choose a random answer from a list. So I've created a list and want that one random answer gets printed in the terminal when you type Hi, Hello (or other greetings).

I've created a list and beneath that random.choice(greeting) to choose a random answer, if the user types Hi. 
When I'm typing Hi, it is not giving me an answer.

So here's the part of the code, I've mentioned:

```py
if input() == "Hi" or "Hello" or "Good Morning" or "Good Afternoon" or "Good Evening" or "Hey":
    greeting = "Hey, how are you today?", "Nice to meet you", "Hello, pleasure to meet you", "Hi human."
    random.choice(greeting)
```

So when I run the code, I get no errors, but when I type Hi, nothing happens. It want it, when I'm typing Hi, Hello, Good Morning, Good Afternoon, Good Evening or Hey, that it picks a random answer from my list ("greeting") and then printing this random answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition never fails because, the first block is

```
input()=="Hi" # might be True or False
input() == "Hi" or "Hello" # is always True no matter what the input is.
```

try this:

```
greeting = "Hey, how are you today?", "Nice to meet you", "Hello, pleasure to meet you", "Hi human."

if input() in ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Good Morning']:
    print(random.choice(greeting)) # random.choice does not print, you need to.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equality check isn't doing what you think.

`if input() in ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Good Morning']:`

Checking if the input is in a list will accomplish what you're trying to do.

Essentially your other check boils down to:

`expression1 or expression2 or expression3`

Where `expression1` is `input() == 'Hi'` and `expression2` is `'Hello'`, even though you were expecting `expression2` to be `input() == 'Hello'`.

Example:

```
>>> import random
>>> if input() in ["Hi", "Hello", "Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good Evening", "Hey"]:
...   greetings = ['sup', 'yo', 'i am so alone']
...   print(random.choice(greetings))
... 
Hi
sup
>>>
```

Comment: @SummerDrummer I updated my answer to include an example done on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice()` selects and returns a random item from the input list, for this item to be displayed you will need to call `print()`. Additionally, you will want to check if the input string is `in` a list of greetings, you might also consider calling `lower()` on the user input so capitalization will not impact matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

if input() in ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Good Morning', "Good Afternoon", "Good Evening", "Hey"]:
  greeting = ["Hey, how are you today?", "Nice to meet you", "Hello, pleasure to meet you", "Hi human."]
  print(random.choice(greeting))
```

**Output**

```
Hi
Hi human.
```

---

```
Good Morning
Hey, how are you today?
```

Comment: Weird. It is working for me. You can also check here https://repl.it/repls/TerrificNoxiousFormula

Comment: Great. Happy to help. Can you give points to this ans so others can also get help through this?

Comment: Says this: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. But there's something, I'd like to ask you: I've made more of those codes above (changing the variable of course), but those don't work. Do you know why?

Comment: Working now. Thanks